# Jquery select option default option text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectbox

I'm trying to populate several select boxes having the same class using jQuery. This is my code

```
populateFieldMapping: function (data,obj) {
        jQuery('.field-mapping select').each(function()
        {
            var option = '<option value="" data-custom-id="_select_">' + "please select a field" + '</option>';
            jQuery.each(data, function (i, res) {
                option += '<option value="' + res.id + '" data-custom-id="' + dataID + '"  data-custom-name="' + res.name + '">' + res.name + '</option>'
            });
            $(this).html(option);
            obj.select2();
        });
    },
```

My HTML

```
<div class="field-mapping">
     <select id="podio-fields-mapping" class="form-control" tabindex="-1">
     </select>
     <select id="podio-fields-mapping" class="form-control" tabindex="-1">
     </select></div>
```

Everything is working fine except I am only getting the "Please select a field" default option for only the first select box. What could be wrong?
I am getting all values in every select box.

```
obj = $('.form-control');
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML?

Comment: what `obj` in `obj.select2();`, can't it be `$(this).select2();`?

Comment: also use .append and not .html

Comment: `var option = '<option value="" data-custom-id="_select_">' + "please select a field" + '</option>',` what is this last *comma* ? Is this throwing an exception on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some typos, I'm afraid:

```
jQuery('.field-mapping select').each(function()
{
    var option = '<option value="" data-custom-id="_select_">' + "please select a field" + '</option>', // <- here you have a ',' instead of ';'
    jQuery.each(data, function (i, res) {
            option += '<option value="' + res.id + '" data-custom-id="' + dataID + '"  data-custom-name="' + res.name + '">' + res.name + '</option>'
    }}); // <- here you have an aditional '}'
    $(this).html(option);
 });
```

Please check you console for errors.

You also can't have two elements with the same `id="podio-fields-mapping"` in your markup.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o3d1njg6/).

Comment: `,` is not syntax error. `}` is, yes. I suppose `.html()` is better there than `.append()`. Don't know about `obj.select2();`

Comment: @mplungjan this code **is** inside a loop, actually.

Comment: That additional } was added by mistake. Thanks for pointing out. I will try out other 2 things you mentioned and let you know.

Comment: @Regent OP is looping through the `select` elements and creating a *select2* widget on each, but `obj` comes from outside.

Comment: @Regent Idk, ask him, why he's selecting `jQuery('.field-mapping select')` if he is passing the `obj`?

Comment: It's not that 'obj.select2()' doesn't make any difference as it's just to trigger the select box if any further ajax call is made.Question is now edited.Removed 'obj.select2()'.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown.. :'jQuery('.field-mapping select')' because I want to repeat the operation for each select box in the division having class 'field-mapping'.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Thanks for helping guys. As you guys said it was having some errors. And I was using same ID for 2 select boxes. Changed everything as you guys said and it's WORKING now. :)

Comment: @Nivin nice to hear that.

Comment: @Nivin can you accept this as the accepted answer, if it was ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is way more readable and is using jQuery to its fullest

```
populateFieldMapping: function (data,obj) {
  jQuery('.field-mapping select').each(function() {
    var options = [];
    $sel = $(this);
    options.push($('<option/>',
     {"value":"", 
      "data-custom-id":"_select_",
      "text":"please select a field"})

    jQuery.each(data, function (i, res) {
      options.push($('<option/>',
        {"value":res.id,
         "data-custom-id":dataID,
         "data-custom-name=":res.name,
         "text":res.name});
    });
    $sel.empty().append(options);
  });
},
```

Comment: If you can create all the html, I its better to attach it once at the instead of appending it each iteration, like OP is doing.

Comment: Sure I agree, but if you have 2 items it will result in 6 `append()` and 6 `text()` instead of just one `html()`.

Comment: Ok, changed to using an array to not manipulate the DOM too much